# MediaPlayer isn't working. OnPrepare isn't executing

Tags: android

Tried everything that I could think of (including the resulting (-38,0) error)
Created a onPreparedListener and now it isn't executing. All of the recommended files and variables established are called and declared.
This is only a snippet of the entire project, it's immense and a lot of it is trivial to the issue at hand.

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.death_march);
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Track loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            playButton.setEnabled(true);
            mp.start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: The `create()` methods are static methods on `MediaPlayer` that return a `MediaPlayer` instance that has already had `prepare()` called. You would use it like `mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(...);`, and it would be prepared right after that. Do note that that is a blocking call, so it will hang your UI thread if called on it.

Comment: Prepare makes an error on calling it. Every time. Unsure why though.

Comment: If you use `create()`, _do not_ call `prepare()`. As mentioned, `prepare()` will have already been called on the returned instance.

Comment: That's for if it's a URI. This is a raw file, in the project itself.

Comment: Creates an error because it's not a URI
`try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.death_march);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new...etc`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say, but perhaps you should have a read through [the docs for `MediaPlayer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) , specifically [`MediaPlayer#create(Context, int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create(android.content.Context,%20int)).

Comment: I have and tried their "procedures" and still results in a (-38, 0) error, even though it should be working
This give an error:
`mediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.death_march);
        mediaPlayer.start();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call `mediaPlayer.create()` on your variable instance. Instead use `MediaPlayer.create()`.

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext, R.raw.death_march);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: I had to redo it multiple times, but thank you. Upvoting, nonetheless